# Are both of these syntax's correct when using loaders Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I've noticed two different uses of including loaders in Webpack. The first one seems more explicit, wrapping the loader in a specific rule:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {test: ..., loader: ...}
    ]
}
```

Whereas the second seems like shorthand, but the only documentation I've found that might clarify this is [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-loaders), but this mentions `Rule.loaders` instead of `module.loaders`.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
       ...
    ]
}
```

Do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `module.rules` and `module.loaders` are valid. `module.rules` has been introduced in webpack 2 with a new and improved loader configuration, but `module.loaders` is still accepted to make the transition easier. *Be aware that webpack 2 will completely ignore `module.loaders` if `module.rules` is present*.

The rules don't really change, but the loader definition in the rules. For me this is another good reason why it has been renamed, because rules are not loaders and this makes it less confusing. To elaborate on this, `module.rules` is a set of rules where each rule applies one or multiple loaders when its condition is satisfied. A loader is a JavaScript module that transforms the given input to valid JavaScript, the input could be anything (e.g. JS, CSS, plain text, etc.) and only the appropriate loaders will know how to handle these input types correctly.

The loader definition has been improved, for example you can now define options on each loader as JavaScript object instead of having to build a string with all options in a query style. Concretely the difference looks like this:

**webpack 1**

```
{
  test: /\.css/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
}
```

**webpack 2**

```
{
  test: /\.css/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader'
      options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The webpack 2 version is much easier to read or modify. Imagine if you had options on `style-loader` as well, or even more loaders, the string representation would just get out of hand (even with string concatenation).

There is also a difference with `use`, `loaders` and `loader` in the rule, although they might work interchangeably in most cases, they should be treated differently.

`use` takes an array of loaders (`loader` is an alias for `use` for compatibility reasons):

```
use: ['babel-loader']
```

`loader` is a shorthand for defining a single rule:

```
loader: 'babel-loader'
// Equivalent to
use: ['babel-loader']
```

Each loader in `use` can be either an object or a string, where the string is just another shorthand version.

```
use: ['babel-loader']
// Equivalent to
use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]
```

The object variant allows you to use options as shown in the `.css` example above.

Another shortcut you might see in some configs is that you can define `options` directly on the rule if you use `loader`. Remember, that is a single loader and webpack will complain if you try it with multiple loaders.

This should give you an overview of rules and loader definitions, but it doesn't cover everything, there are still other ways (e.g. passing a function to `use`). Feel free to read the [source for the rules](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/RuleSet.js), the comments at the beginning are already helpful, but they don't cover everything either.